# angularjs - dynamically add a variable to the scope of each controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to add a global viable to the scope of all controllers

i can do it manually in each controller like...

if variable is

```
<script>
    var base_url ="http://localhost/myapp/";
</stript>
```

then

```
app.controller('myController',[$scope','$window',
    function($scope, $window) {
      $scope.base_url = $window.base_url;
    }
]);
```

i can also use `$rootScope` or `service`

but i want to add this variable to the scope of each controller dynamically. So as there any possible way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Possible solution:**

If it's more a constant than a variable that you need to pass to all the controllers, so for example it's an URL that never change you can use angular method `constant`

Example:

```
app.constant('BASE_URL','http://localhost/myapp/');
```

Then in each controller you inject it:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope','BASE_URL' , function ($scope, BASE_URL){
  $scope.base_url = BASE_URL;
}])
```

**Alternatives:**

- Services
- $rootScope

Answer (score 0):

There is a `base` tag that support angular to make sure that every URL in your javascript (templates, $http,...) will be relative to that one. So you can just use it : https://docs.angularjs.org/#!/guide/$location

Others way are :

1. $rootScope as you mentioned
2. Events, all controller require that value can listen for a specific event to get the new value.
3. Service. Either $watch is value or use events again
4. If it has not to changed and you can know the value at bootstrap you can use `angular.constant` to define and then inject a constant balue. This one seems to be out of subject for you though.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative for controller input is ng-init directive.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl as $ctrl" 
     ng-init="$ctrl.init({baseUrl: 'http://localhost/myapp/'})"></div>

 angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl', function () {
      this.init = function (inputData) {
           console.log(inputData); // {baseUrl: 'http://localhost/myapp/'}
            this.baseUrl = inputData.baseUrl;
      }
});
```